# Django ORM queryset takes integer filed as string

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

```
results = UmUrl.objects \
            .filter(created_at__gte=sdate, created_at__lte=edate) \
            .annotate(timeValue=self.get_date_format(param)) \
            .values('timeValue') \
            .order_by('timeValue') \
            .annotate(blocked=Sum(Case(When(operation=0, then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField()))) \
            .annotate(unBlocked=Sum(Case(When(operation=1, then=1), default=0, output_field=models.IntegerField())))
```

'operation' filed is Integer type. This code creates an sql query, but in the sql reult 'when' parameters is shown as string type. So that it does not work.

sql output like that. How can I solve this problem?

```
{"query": "SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(EXTRACT('year' FROM \"um_url\".\"created_at\" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Istanbul'), CONCAT('-', EXTRACT('month' FROM \"um_url\".\"created_at\" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Istanbul'))) AS \"timeValue\", SUM(CASE WHEN \"um_url\".\"operation\" = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS \"blocked\", SUM(CASE WHEN \"um_url\".\"operation\" = '1' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS \"unBlocked\" FROM \"um_url\" WHERE (\"um_url\".\"created_at\" <= '2018-06-02 15:47:51.857000+00:00' AND \"um_url\".\"created_at\" >= '2018-06-01 15:47:51.857000+00:00') GROUP BY CONCAT(EXTRACT('year' FROM \"um_url\".\"created_at\" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Istanbul'), CONCAT('-', EXTRACT('month' FROM \"um_url\".\"created_at\" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Istanbul'))) ORDER BY \"timeValue\" ASC", "empty_check": "true"}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: yes I fixed it, It occured from my custom API. The developer replaced all parameters like this query.replace("%s","'%s'") % tuple(params). So I changed it like that query % tuple(custom_params)

Comment: in the custom_params I just replace string parameters, not integer or others like that